# Firebase Realtime Database Not Saving Data online only Offline

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I made a web application in firebase using the integrated realtime database. I am a beginner in firebase but have had it work in the past. Basically I can save data in the DB while using my files offline but after I have deployed all my files the data will not save.

Key Points. 
I have installed and used all necessary Libraries.
Have deployed over and over again. 
Pretty sure code is correct since offline it saves correctly. here is a small snippet of JS file

Thank you in advance.

```
 var database = firebase.database();
function clickimage()
{

    var id = document.getElementById("id");
    var marca = document.getElementById("marca");
    var tipo = document.getElementById("tipo");
    var desc = document.getElementById("desc");
    var depa = document.getElementById("depa");
    var precio = document.getElementById("precio");

    firebase.database().ref("Ingresado").push({
        producto: {
            numero_id: id.value,
            marca: marca.value,
            tipo: tipo.value,
            descripcion: desc.value,
            departamento: depa.value,
            precio: precio.value
        }
    }).key;


}
```